# Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DataReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, namespace

Boa tarde, estava a realizar um código para fazer uma query a minha base de dados quando me apareceu estes erro: Error  1   The type or namespace name 'DataReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Sei que é algo simples mas se me pudessem dar uma ajuda ficava bastante grato.
Aqui esta o código:

```
   {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=DB_SACC; User id=sa Password=1234;";
        decimal? average;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    string textt = "SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) AS 'AVG_DIVIDA' FROM t_pagamentos";
                    cmd.CommandText = textt;
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    using (DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            average = decimal.parse(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"].ToString());
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            TextBox3.Text = average.HasValue ? average.ToString() : "Unknown error occurred";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve the average, reason: " + ex.Message);


        }
```

Comment: Experimente substituir: DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() por: var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader().

Comment: resultou , mas agora esta a dar o seguinte erro : Error 1 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'parse'.

Comment: quer dizer este erro:Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'average'

Comment: Basta declarar a variável: var average = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"].ToString());

Comment: obrigado a todos este foi o erro que se deu despois de ter seguido o conselho de senhor Marcell  : Error 1 A local variable named 'average' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'average', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Answer (score 1):

O método `ExecuteReader()` retorna um `SqlDataReader`:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente substituir o tipo do reader para `var` no `using` e verificar se o valor que está chegando não é `null`:

```
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=DB_SACC; User id=sa Password=1234;";
    decimal? average;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                string textt = "SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) AS 'AVG_DIVIDA' FROM t_pagamentos";
                cmd.CommandText = textt;
                connection.Open();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        average = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"].toString());
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        TextBox3.Text = average.HasValue ? average.ToString() : "Unknown error occurred";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve the average, reason: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: ja experimentei e esta a surguir o seguinte erro :Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'average '

Comment: decimal? average; remove o nullable. Põe: decimal average = 0;

Comment: Basta declarar a variável: var average = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"].toString());

Comment: obrigado a todos este foi o erro que se deu despois de ter seguido o conselho de senhor Marcell : Error 1 A local variable named 'average' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'average', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: @DiogoGomes É só você ler o texto que vai entender qual é o problema.

Comment: eu percebi qual é o erro nao estou é a entender como devo resolve lo. obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @DiogoGomes testou remover o nullable?

Comment: ok ja esta a dar , apesar que diz que falhou o login em user sa e na password